# Combining sum formulas or a way to include additional variables in the formula

Tags: excel, date, sum

I have two working formulas for two cells in Excel but I want to combine them into one cell.

Is there a way to just combine the formulas or show me how to include the other letters in the same formula?

I have Column A with dates and column B with letters: `L`, `S`, `U`. I have the following formulas that add up the letters independently because I couldn't find a way to combine them in one formula:

```
=SUM((COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$199,">="&H2,$B$5:$B$199,"="&"S")))
=SUM((COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$199,">="&H2,$B$5:$B$199,"="&"U")))
=SUM((COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$199,">="&H2,$B$5:$B$199,"="&"L")/2))
```

Keep note that the `L` needs to be divided by `2` so that might be what makes this trickier. I'm fine with just combining the `S` and `U` and keeping the `L` separate but if you know who to combine them all I'm all for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this condensed version

`=SUM(COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$199,">="&H2,$B$5:$B$199,{"S","U","L"})/{1,1,2})`

You have to divide all of them so the trick is to divide the `"S"` and `"U"` totals by 1, thus retaining the existing values

Comment: I wish I was as good as you guys with this - its like poetry !

Answer (score 0):

There may well be a neater way were it not for the halving, but with it a long-winded approach may be good enough:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$199,">="&H3,$B$5:$B$199,"="&"S"),COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$199,">="&H3,$B$5:$B$199,"="&"U"),COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$199,">="&H3,$B$5:$B$199,"="&"L")/2)
```